# Feed tensorflow or keras neural nets input with custom dimensions

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I would like to feed a neural net inputs of following shape:
Each training entry is a 2D array with dimensions 700x10. There are in total 204 training entries.
Labels is just 1-dimensional array of size 204 (binary output)

I tried to just use Dense layers:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(300, activation='relu', input_shape=(700, 10)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

But then I am getting following error (not related to input_shape on the first layer, but during validation of output):

```py
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (204, 1)
```

204 - amount of training data.

Stacktrace:

```py
    model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, epochs=4, batch_size=6)
  File "keras\models.py", line 867, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "keras\engine\training.py", line 1522, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "keras\engine\training.py", line 1382, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "keras\engine\training.py", line 132, in _standardize_input_data
```

What I found out while debugging Keras code:

It fails during validation before training. It validates output array.

According to the neural network structure, first Dense layer produces somehow 700, 1 dimensional output and it fails afterwards, since my output is just 1-d array with 204 in it.

How do I overcome this issue? I tried to add Flatten() after Dense() layer, but it probably affects accuracy in a bad way: I would like to keep information specific to one point from 700 array grouped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Dense` layers works on only one dimension, the last.

If you're inputting `(700,10)` to it, it will output `(700,units)`. Check your `model.summary()` to see this.

A simple solution is to flatten your data before applying dense:

```
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(700,10)))
model.add(Dense(300,...))
model.add(Dense(1,...))
```

This way, the Dense layer will see a simple `(7000,)` input.

---

Now if you do want your model to understand those 2 dimensions separately, you should perhaps try more elaborated structures. What to do will depend a lot on what your data is and what you want to do, how you want your model to understand it, etc.

Comment: Okay, thank you for model.summary() tip! Will try to further investigate Keras and what it has to offer more thoroughly

Comment: Can you describe the data? If the 700 vectors are time steps, for instance, you can use recurrent networks, like GRU and LSTM. If it's a physical length, it might be interesting to use 1D convolutions.